# Silex Defining Access Rules

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I follow the Silex documention section http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-access-rules

And here is my confirguration

```
'security.role_hierarchy' => [
    'ROLE_ADMIN' => [
        'ROLE_USER',
    ],
    'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => [
        'ROLE_USER',
        'ROLE_ADMIN',
        'ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH'
    ]
],
'security.access_rules' => [
    [ '^.*$', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' ],
    [ '^/account', 'ROLE_USER' ],
    [ '^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN' ]
]
```

So what I need is quite simple, an anonymous user can access everywhere (except the /account/* and /admin/* paths), a user with "ROLE_USER" can access averywhere and /account/* paths, but not /admin/* paths, and a user with "ROLE_ADMIN" can access everywhere.

I make a very basic controller to test if a user is redirected if he's not a "ROLE_ADMIN":

```
$app->get('/admin', function () use ($app) {

    return 1;
})->bind('admin');
```

But not at all. He can acces to /admin, with a printed "1" on the page...

According to the doc:

```
With the above configuration, users must have the ROLE_ADMIN to access the /admin section of the website [...] (if that's not the case, the user will be automatically redirected).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely the order of the rules is important, only one will be matched. Silex will look at each starting at the top, and stop as soon as it finds one `security.access_rules` entry that matches the URL, in other words, Silex will decide which `security.access_rules` to use based on the URI and the first rule that matches is used. So you need move the first rule to end to resolve this:

```
'security.access_rules' => [
    [ '^/account', 'ROLE_USER' ],
    [ '^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN' ],
    [ '^.*$', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' ],
]
```